# CSV Parse has empty cells

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I'm reading a line from a CSV with Python 3.5 and am missing something quite basic:

```
s = '"Cats wheels.","Womp"\n'
reader = csv.reader(s)
for j in reader: print(j)
```

I expect this to print just two cells, but it prints:

```
['Cats wheels.']
['', '']
['Womp']
[]
```

Does anyone know how I can get just a two cell parse here?

Comment: Can you try using  csv.reader(s,delimiter=',')

Comment: I tried that my good sir, but the result doth not please me

Comment: My bad made a silly suggestion!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because `csv.reader` expects a file object and iterate through it.  Quote from [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader):

> `csvfile` can be any object which supports the iterator protocol and
>   returns a string each time its `__next__()` method is called — file
>   objects and list objects are both suitable.

Observe the difference when it's reading from `StringIO`:

```
import io
s = '"Cats wheels.","Womp"\n'
buff_s = io.StringIO(s)
reader = csv.reader(buff_s)
for j in reader:
    print(j)

# ['Cats wheels.', 'Womp']
```

To answer your question in comment: `csv.reader` does its type check against `Iterator`s, e.g.:

```
[j for j in csv.reader(123)]   # reader on int type

# ... Traceback ... #
# TypeError: argument 1 must be an iterator
```

That said, the `str` type *is* supported because it iterates, just that it's painfully useless on its own because `iter(some_str)` is split by empty string `''`, so each char is treated as a newline.  If you really want to parse by string, you could specify how to `split` your string like this:

```
for j in csv.reader(s.split('\n')):
    print(j)


# ['Cats wheels.', 'Womp']
# []
```

Comment: Why do you think the csv module refrains from typechecking inputs? Seems if the reader gets a string it should use io.StringIO to parse it? Is there ever a situation in which a string input's iterable items would be appropriate to parse?

Comment: It *does* in fact typecheck (try `csv.reader(123)`), just that it's checking if the input is an `iterator`. Being a dynamic type language it makes sense for python's builtin package not be overly restrictive on type provided it can return the expected data structure.  In fact, as you observed `str` type is supported because it can be iterated, just not particularly useful since `str` is split by empty string `''` so every char will be its new line.  In your case, the quoting of `"` took precedence.  Try `csv.reader(s, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)` and you'll see the difference.

Comment: I updated my answer to your second part of the question in your comment.  You could still make use of `str` without `StringIO`, but at that point you might as well `.split('\n') ... .split(',')` yourself.

Comment: Yes, my point is just that it'd be more reasonable if the reader used `io.StringIO(s)` on input strings rather than iterating over the raw string itself. I don't see any valid use case for treating the raw string as an iterable in that function...

Comment: I don't know the implementation details, but it would seem the reader is indiscriminate against the object being passed as long as it can be iterated, and treat each iterated sub-item as a new line for further parsing, which is why you observe the split by `''` when passing a raw string.  Since the reader already handle iterable objects, it is up to the user to define how they want that object to be treated by the reader.  Too much hand holding for various object types would make the reader unnecessarily complicated to manage, methinks.

Answer (score 0):

This code will remove the unwanted comma and newline.

```
import csv
s = '"Cats wheels.","Womp"\n'
reader = csv.reader(s.strip ().replace (',', ''))
for j in reader: print(j)
```